# CSS Button link add multiple different images

Tags: html, css, image, button

I have a link that is style as a button, but I would like to add images to this button without duplicating the same CSS.  I have one version that doesn't have an image, then one with an 'Edit' icon, one with a 'Delete' icon.  So...basically I have three CSS classes that are 95% the same with the exception of the background image properties.  Here is the Edit and Delete button:

```
.deleteButtonClass2 {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0px #97c4fe;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0px #97c4fe;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0px #97c4fe;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff7f00), color-stop(1, #bf5f00) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100% );
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff7f00', endColorstr='#bf5f00');
    background-image: url('delete-page-red.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 4px;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-color: #ff7f00;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    text-indent: 0;
    border: 1px solid #331900;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #1570cd;
}


.editButtonClass2 {
    ......
    background-image: url('edit-yellow.gif');   <-- Only Difference 
    ..........
}
```

How can I reduce the CSS so that if I decide to change the button color, I don't have as many places to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use multiple classes! Here's the principal

### HTML

```
<div class="button edit"></div>
<div class="button delete"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.button {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.edit {
  background-color: blue;
}

.delete {
  background-color: green;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/BnE82/**

Note how the repeated/shared code is in one class and we've broken the unique parts in to separate classes. The HTML elements are assigned multiple classes; the repeated/shared class (`button`) and their own separate class for the unique items.

Combined they create the full effects!

Comment: That's what I initially tried, but I think the issue is that the main button class has a gradient background setting which was overwriting the 'editButton' image background.  If I take off the gradient it works.  Any idea if I can do the gradient WITH the image?

Comment: Hi @MattS. Can you knock up a JSFiddle to illustrate please?

Comment: Here's one:  http://jsfiddle.net/mschumacker/tRKhN/4/

But, the gradient doesn't work in jsfiddle, so it works fine.  If I take the same thing and throw is on a page in Chrome, it doesn't work.  I could just get rid of the gradient as I really don't need it.

Comment: @MattS. aha, I understand. Unfortunately elements can only have one background image so what's happening is that the `.editButton`'s `background-image` is overwriting that of the `.blueButton`. Here's an alternative approach: http://jsfiddle.net/tRKhN/5/

Comment: Perfect...Thanks.  This is why I'm a developer and not a designer.

Comment: @MattS. says the man who has come up with the complicated, fancy button? :-P

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried multiple classes?

I.e. have your button class

```
.buttonClass {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0px #97c4fe;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0px #97c4fe;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0px #97c4fe;
    background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff7f00), color-stop(1, #bf5f00) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ff7f00 5%, #bf5f00 100% );
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff7f00', endColorstr='#bf5f00');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 4px;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-color: #ff7f00;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    text-indent: 0;
    border: 1px solid #331900;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #1570cd;
}
```

And then have the individual classes for each of the items (i.e. Delete, Edit etc.)

```
.delete {
    background-image: url('delete-page-red.gif');
}

.edit {
    background-image: url('edit-yellow.gif');
}
```

Then on you button you would set the class as follows :

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" class="buttonClass delete" />
<input type="button" value="Edit" class="buttonClass edit" />
```